# What is this square icon and square + triangle icon in Mac OS X bar?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, applications, icon

From left, second one(to the right to Evernote)

As well as the fourth one.

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you click on them?

Comment: This is not my Mac, I have seen them many times in other place. This is a picture I got by accident.  I thought it might be very popular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second menulet from the left is [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) - a tool to customize keyboard and some mouse/trackpad settings.

[image: Karabiner menulet]

Please note that some colors in the menubar are inverted

Answer (score 3):

The fourth one is a program called [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) - a window manager similar to [Flexiglass](http://nulana.com/flexiglass/) or [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/).

[image: screenshot SizeUp]